# I cannot collect data from API using Axios + React

Tags: reactjs, axios, use-effect

I'm beginner with React. I have 2 different cases where I'm using React Hooks which I cannot receive the data from my local API properly.

Case 1:

```
    export const RegisterT = () => {

        const [test, setTest] = useState()

        const addrState = {}

        axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:3333/states', { addrState })
         .then(res => {

            setTest(res.data)

            console.log(test)

        })

    ...

    }
```

It works with the state `test` displaying correctly the content from the API but I don't know why/how the Axios continues calling the API infinity - endless. (Ps: the very first call it returns undefined, then the next ones it works) What am I doing wrong?

To fix this I've tried to use `useEffect` like this (Case 2):

```
export const RegisterT = () => {

    const [test, setTest] = useState()

    const addrState = {}

    useEffect(() => {

        axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:3333/states', { addrState })
            .then(res => {

                setTest(res.data)

                console.log(test);

            })

    }, [])

...

}
```

Now the Axios works only once but no data is coming from the API. Maybe I should use async/wait for this case but I cannot make it work. Does anyone know how to fix that (Case 1 or/and Case 2)?

Thanks.

Comment: I think Case2 is correct, but remember that updating the state is an asynchronous operation, which means `test` is still not updated when you try to `console.log`, please try to move the `console.log` outside the `useEffect` hook and check it again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updating the state is an asynchronous operation. So the `state` is not really updated until the next time the component gets rendered. If you want to capture the correct state, you can either `console.log(res.data)` or wrap that inside the `useEffect` hook with `test` as dependency.

```js
export const RegisterT = () => {

    const [test, setTest] = useState()

    const addrState = {}

   // effect only runs when component is mounted
    useEffect(() => {
        axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:3333/states', { addrState })
            .then(res => {
                setTest(res.data);
            });

    }, []);
    
    // effect runs whenever value of test changes
    useEffect(() => {
        console.log(test);
    }, [test]); 

}
```

That way it is guaranteed that the `console.log` runs when the value of `test` is updated.

Also the reason the API request is invoked once is you have not mentioned anything in the dependency array. `[]` empty dependency array runs the effect when the component is mounted for the first time.

`async/await` is just a wrapper around `Promise` object. So they would behave similarly.

Answer (score 1):

The solution with `useEffect` is good. If you don't use it each render will call the request. This is the same if you put there `console.log` with any information. The reason why you don't see the data in the `useEffect` is that the value of the state is not updated in current render but in the next which is called by setter of the state. Move the `console.log(test);` after `useEffect` to see the data. On init it will be `undefined` but in the next render, it should contain the data from the request.